# Dynamicaly change children div height based on parent div height using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem with dynamically changing children `<div>` height  based on parent `<div>` height

Here is the example

```
<div id="parent" style="height:600px">
<div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

And js

```
var mapWidth = $("#parent").height() - 50; 
var sidebarWith = $("#children").height();

if (sidebarWith > mapWidth) { 
     $("#children").height(mapWidth);
} else {
     $("#children").height(sidebarWith); 
}
```

Parent `<div>` have fixed height but children `<div>` change his height using jQuery `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` functions.

If children `<div>` height is greater than parent I need to set height of children `<div>` to parent `<div>`. Also when I slideUp in children `<div>` and if children `<div>` height after `slideUp()` is lower that parent `<div>` height I need to set height of children `<div>` to his current height.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? May you do a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: instead of posting this in comment edit your question please .

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the following fiddle and see if the result is as expected (click on the underlined text to see t): http://jsfiddle.net/gabi/uHnKs/

Note that slideUp() first reduces the height of the element to 0 and hides it and you can see a flicker on slide finish. You might want to use animate() and alter the height of the element:

```
$('#children p').on('click', function() {

    var cHeight = $('#children').height() + 'px';

    if ($('#children').height() > $("#parent").height() - 50) { 
         cHeight = ($("#parent").height() - 50) + 'px'; 
    } 

    $('#children').animate({'height' : cHeight});       

});
```